# JQPlot bar-chart fill set as false

Tags: jqplot, bar-chart

how to set bar chart fill as false? so only the outline of the bar chart is shown.

i know Pyramid Renderer allows us to set fill as false but pyramid chart style is not exactly the chart i'm looking for.

Comment: E.g. Pyramid chart: http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/kcp_pyramid2.html

Comment: According to me, this functionality is still not present inside barRenderer. you have to make changes inside the library to make this happen.